# Constructing a trace matrix using Python

Tags: requirements-engineering

I'm working on a writing integration tests for an API with around 300 methods. I have a collection of Python scripts that can tell me what methods are tested and what files each method is being tested in. This is good enough for personal use but it isn't the best format for sharing this information with the project manager.

I'd rather not construct the trace matrix by hand. Are there existing solutions for generating trace matrices in Python?

Comment: I've not personally tried this. I know this link is available in python. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mlx.traceability/1.3.0

Comment: There are a number of modules you can potentials use to achieve what you are after, check this link, https://blog.modeanalytics.com/python-data-visualization-libraries/